# Continuos deployment to a autoscaling group in private subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, continuous-deployment, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I've an elb in public subnet using an autoscaling group comprising of 3 private subnets, each running 2 ec2 instances and a NAT instance In a public subnet.

Due to certain restrictions I can't use aws codedeploy or code pipeline or even s3.

Now my question is that how can I still deploy my latest github commits to each of my ec2 instances automatically?

Any suggestions would be very welcome indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have windows machines in your auto scaling group, create and configure a task in the image used for auto scaling so that it copies the latest version of the application from a deployment server. You can run this task at start up of the group instances.